# jQuery - 2 dropdown's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like that :

[`HERE`](http://jsfiddle.net/JM745/1/)

I need to repair that to : I see 2 dropdowns on website. When on start I haven't select nothing from first dropdown in the second is nothing (when i try check him first).

Any help?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate a little.

Comment: Already updated my question. Is little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:-

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EVxNE/)

```
var id = this.value;//Get the value of the option.
var options = $(this).data('options'); //get all the saved options.

if (id) { //if there is value then filter it out
    options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
}
$('#select2').html(options).prop('selectedIndex', 0); //save option and set selectedindex to first element.
```

Comment: I little elaborated my question, so maybe you understand me better. It's still not that what i want. I try to do that by myself but that already tooks me hours ;d

Comment: @Chris Sorry, i did not understand. Can you elaborate.

Comment: @Chris Is that the answer? Not sure what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$("#select1").change(function () {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
        /*Taking an array of all options-2 and
              kind of embedding it on the select1*/
        $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options;
    if( id === '') {
        options = $(this).data('options');
    }
    else {
        options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
    }
    $('#select2').html(options);
}).change();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/JM745/2/)**